# How to change Quill editor's responsive toolbar group ordering in Bubble theme?

Tags: css, responsive-design, quill

I am using `quill.js`, which is amazing btw, on a responsive website and would like the toolbar elements on the left (i.e. bold, italic, underline, etc.) to be the last item in the responsive column group as the page gets smaller.  This will allow the most frequently used items like bold/underline to be accessible to mobile users when the editor is too small to accommodate the entire responsive bubble toolbar (sometimes it goes off the screen when the parent container's height hasn't expanded with enough content).  By default, the toolbar elements on the left are grouped 'first' instead of 'last'.

Does anyone have an idea on how to change the responsive ordering of the bubble theme's toolbar elements?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.